# Ajax testing with Mocha - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I tried using Mocha to write tests for one of my application.
I can able to run different scenarios when page reloads.

Consider the below scenario

**1) A user enters value in a text field "Username"**

**2) Clicks "Save" button**

**3) This will send ajax call to save user name and response might come    back in 1 to 2 seconds**

**4) A message is shown after response is received**

How can i implement test for above scenario?

NOTE : I tried the below code, but the browser isn't waiting at all

```
  describe("Ajax test", function(){

        before(function(){
            return this.browser.field('save').click() 
        })

    it("Tests save username", function(){

        this.browser.wait(6000, function() {
          //code to check if success message is shown in body
        })
    })
  })
```

thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a callback you can make in each test case, and you should wait for a response from the server before making this callback.

The pattern should be something like this:

```
// Test case.  Notice the `done` param
it('Should make an async call', function(done){

    // Make an async call, with a callback function
    async_call(function(){

        // Do whatever you need (test some values)
        // Then call done
        done();
    });
});
```