# Testing a socket.on('data') callback without having mocha time out

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

Trying to wrap my head around TCP servers in node and testing in Mocha!

Here's what I've done so far:

In tcp-server.js

```
'use strict';
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = module.exports.server = net.createServer(function(socket){
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data.toString());
    var requestString = "Requested on: " + new Date().toString() + "\n" + data.toString();
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("datalog.log", {'flags': 'a'});
    writeStream.write(requestString);
    writeStream.end();
  });

  socket.on('end', function(){
    console.log('socket closed');
  });
});

server.listen('3000', function(){
  console.log('server up');
});
```

And in test.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var server = require(__dirname + "/../tcp-server.js").server;
var request = require('superagent');

describe('the tcp server', function() {

  beforeEach(function(){
    server.listen('3000', function(){
      console.log('server up in mocha!');
    });
  });

  it('should log all requests to a log file', function(done){
  request.get('http://localhost:3000').end(function(err, res){
    expect(true).to.equal(false); //This test doesn't run
    //eventually write some fs code that tests if the log file is written to;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

It looks like the console.log(data.toString()) line in tcp-server.js fires, but the console.log does not update. The log only seems to update when there's a timeout in mocha (ie there is no done() call).

Any ideas how I can make sure that everything that should execute after the 'data' event does execute, so that I can check that the log was updated?

Thanks!

EDIT: the problem was not with the test, but with the TCP server (I didn't close it properly).

In tcp-server.js

```
'use strict';
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = module.exports.server = net.createServer(function(socket){
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    var requestString = data.toString();
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("datalog.log", {'flags': 'a'});
    writeStream.write(requestString);
    writeStream.end();
    socket.end();
  });

  socket.on('end', function(){
    console.log('socket closed');
    server.close();
  });
});

server.listen('3000', function(){
  console.log('server up');
});

var client = net.connect({port: 3000},
    function() { //'connect' listener
  console.log('connected to server!');
  client.write("Requested on: " + new Date().toString() + "\n");
});
```

And in test.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var server = require(__dirname + "/../tcp-server.js").server;

describe('the tcp server', function() {
  var logstringBefore = "";
  var logstringAfter = "";

  before(function(done){
    fs.readFile('datalog.log', function(err, data){
      logstringBefore = data.toString();
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should log all requests to a log file and change it', function(done){
    server.listen('3000', function(){
    var requestString = "Requested on: " + new Date().toString();
      console.log('server up in mocha!');
      fs.readFile('datalog.log', function(err, data){
        logstringAfter = data.toString();
        expect(logstringAfter).to.include(requestString);
        expect(logstringBefore).to.not.equal(logstringAfter);
        done();
       });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax testing with Mocha - Nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166591/ajax-testing-with-mocha-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

`done()` should be called after `end()` has finished executing i.e. when the callback is triggered like shown below.

Also consider re-factoring the code like below. `server.listen()` moved to `before()` so it is only executed once for all the `it()` inside the `describe()` with `done()` call back in `server.listen()`. This will make sure the server is ready before `it()` executes.

```
describe('the tcp server', function() {

  before(function(done){
    server.listen('3000', function(){
      console.log('server up in mocha!');
      done();
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(){});

  it('should log all requests to a log file', function(done){
    request.get('http://localhost:3000').end(function(err, res){
      expect(true).to.equal(false);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the done() statement up there will run the test, but the socket doesn't seem to stay open long enough to write to the log file...I think.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Do let me know if that solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the done call should work! I forgot to close the server in  tcp-server.js!